# Triage - Requires Editing or Looks OK?

Tags: discussion, triage

If I edit the question by visiting the link in Triage, after editing should I click "Requires Editing" or "Looks OK" ?

---

If I want to edit the question without going to Help & Improvement review,

Should I click "Looks OK" first then edit ?
or

Should I edit first and then click "Looks OK" ?

Comment: You dont have an edit link in triage queue.. You mean visit the link and edit?

Comment: TL;DR **Requires Editing** means that **you** can edit the question to fix its problems.

Comment: I think [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) is probably a better duplicate target. Although I’m closing as such, I could be persuaded that this question needs a unique answer addressing the confusion that the Triage queue is *only* to triage (identify and sort), not to actually attempt to *fix* the problem(s).

Comment: @Machavity . I click Requires Editing then I edit the question. Is it ok?

Comment: @SmartManoj No. When you click Requires Editing it means you're sending it to the Help and Improvement queue for **other people** to edit. If the user needs to add more information themselves then select **Unsalvageable**

Comment: @Machavity I edit the question and I click Looks OK. Is it fine?

Comment: That could work too. It's a long standing issue that the Requires Editing button is still confusing. Too many people think it makes a user go back and edit their own post, which it does not

Answer (score 4):

Does the post still require editing by the community to be a good question?  If so, choose requires editing.

Is the post a high quality question currently, not needing any improvement?  If so, choose Looks Ok.

How the post *used* to be at some point in the past is irrelevant.

On a side note, if you want to be spending most of your review time editing posts to improve them, Triage isn't really the queue for you.  It's purpose is to determine which posts needs *actual* reviewing, which if needed, takes place in other queues.  If you're going and editing an occasional post when you happen to see something you *really* want to fix, that's fine, but if you're primarily intending to actually fix posts, you should really be reviewing in a queue where that is the actual goal of the queue (Help and Improvement is all about editing, and it's a core part of first/last posts, as well as suggested edits).

Comment: What if it's a low-quality question but does not need any substantial improvement, such as grammatical errors, or greetings or sign-offs (hey guys etc.)

Comment: @kjhf If it's a low quality question then it, by definition, needs substantial improvement.  Grammatical changes or removing greetings *aren't* substantial improvements.  If the improvements required of the post for it to be a quality post are not things the community can provide, then you need to flag the post for closure, rather than saying it's okay or that it needs editing.

Comment: agreed about closing unsalvageable. My thoughts are edits are required for it to be a "good question", in order to enforce guidelines, e.g. no signoffs or grammatical errors. But it does not need substantial improvements, and I, or another member, could provide these changes. Should the question be marked as "needs editing"? The linked FAQ on Triage says "If it's a halfway decent question but not amazing, or if some editing would be nice to clean up some minor errors or rough spots, but it's just about as answerable without any, just hit Looks OK." which disagrees with your answer here.

Comment: @kjhf If the question needs editing that can be done by the community, you should choose "needs editing", not "looks okay".  The documentation the site provides about how to use Triage has a long and sordid history of constantly telling people to do exactly the wrong thing.  You should give it no credence whatsoever because no thought has been put into it by the company.